# Python script throws a Memory Error when writing data to csv

Tags: python, csv

I've made an email/phone extraction script. It works perfectly, but when I try to parse the CSV with the website for the extraction there, I ran into problems.

I tried with pandas, but it crashes more often than with this:

```
with open('input.csv', encoding='utf-8') as csv_file:
    for row in csv_file:
        elements = row.split(',')
        website = elements[3]
        emails = phones = ''
        if website == 'N/A':
            emails = phones = 'N/A'
        else:
            email_list = []
            phone_list = []

            email_list = extractUrl(website)
            phone_list = phoneNumberExtract(website)

            print('Emails found -> '+str(email_list))
            print('Phones found -> '+str(phone_list))
            print("")

            if len(email_list) == 0:
                    emails = 'NO EMAILS'
            if len(phone_list) == 0:
                    phones = 'NO PHONES'

            for email in email_list:
                    emails += email + '/'

            for phone in phone_list:
                    phones += phone + '/'


        output_row = elements[0] + ',' + elements[1] + ',' + elements[2] + ',' + elements[3] + ',' + elements[4] + ',' + elements[5] + ',' + emails + ',' + phones + ',' + '\n'
        with open('output.csv', mode="a", encoding='utf-8') as output_csv:
            output_csv.write(output_row)
```

After about ~1000 rows, it crashes and throws a Memory Error like this one:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "script.py", line 299, in <module>
        output_csv.write(output_row)
    MemoryError
```

Can someone explain to me where I went wrong?

Comment: I can't see what's causing the memory error, but you're certainly missing the point of the csv module at the end there. There's no need to create `output_row` like that; you should just do `output_csv.write(elements)`. And also there's no need to open the output CSV each time, just open it at the start of the loop like you do with the input.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Yes, I understand, there is no need for them, will make those updates.

Comment: can it be that emails and phones together is a very large list? How many for maximum. Try to see for which element it's crashing, try running for that alone single row in CSV.

Comment: I thought that would be a problem, so the list can have a maximum of 10 emails/phones, it crashes sometimes while writing a list with only 1-2 emails/phones

Comment: Please take a look at pandas, making your life and ours so much nicer: https://pandas.pydata.org/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried limiting the amount?

```
import sys
import csv

csv.field_size_limit(sys.maxsize)
```